# Why I failed to make setup when I was trying to install RedisTimeSeries?

Tags: installation, redis, redistimeseries

I just followed what was said in README(https://github.com/RedisTimeSeries/RedisTimeSeries) to install RedisTimeSeries on Ubuntu.[what I did following the document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHa5n.png) But when I tried to execute "make build", it showed [the information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxeyJ.png). And I'm sure that I have already executed "make setup", so I guess I failed to make setup before. I was wondering what was wrong and how I can do to install RedisTimeSeries?

Just like what I said before, I followed the instructions in README and try to install RedisTimeSeries on Ubuntu. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5C6um.png) is what it shows when I make setup. I'm expecting a method which can help me accomplish this task. Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps in https://github.com/RedisTimeSeries/RedisTimeSeries#build-it-yourself. We recently updated this section.

Comment: Sorry it seems that the problem isn't solved. Thank you for your answer anyway.